# How does browser handle http requests

Tags: java, android, browser, webview, httprequest

Hi I have some problems trying to handle http requests on my own and show them on screen using **webview**

Using the
**shouldInterceptRequest**
function in **WebViewClient**

So far, things are fine. I handle the matter well and receive cookies from the response headers and send them again in the next request.

But I'm having problems processing post requests

As the server expects some information from me in the request body, such as the password, email, and some other parameters that differ from one site to another.

Now my problem is how do I know what parameters are required from the server, such as the browser, as the browser handles these requests with ease and dwarfs sending all the required parameters

I tried to monitor requests via **DevTools** in PC **chrome** and I saw what parameters are required to login in only one site

I managed to get these parameters with **javascript** via

```
wb.loadUrl("javascript:const formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form')); for(var pair of formData.entries()){INTER.putForms(pair[0],pair[1]); }");
```

I made a **javainterface** and put in it a putforms function that receives the information and puts it in a hashmap

Now I have solved the problem in one site, what about the rest of the sites? This method is not easy at all, I have to know how the browser deals with these requests

Please Help

Comment: A browser does not receive http requests. A browser sends http requests. And if it posts key=value pairs it can do so while the html source contained a form with such input tags.

Comment: ok ok now i am executing javascript code which gives me the value of each input type and i cant find any of the values ​​that the browser sends

Comment: If you once logged in at stackoverflow then the next day after pc restart the browser will send login username and password without you typed them in in form input fields. So where would they come from?

Comment: From cookies and my problem not in just login some post requests need other parameters